# How to avoid tslint specific rule?

Tags: typescript, tslint

So I'm in a situation where I want for a specific class to be able to disable max-classes-per-file.

However I've tried to add the rule `/* tslint:disable:max-classes-per-file: */`

At the beginning of the file but I still got the warning.

Even doing  `"exclude": [ "src/modules/Utils/Utils.tsx" ]` in my tsconfig.json is not Working.

Im still getting

> web_1      | /usr/app/web/src/modules/Utils/Utils.tsx
>
> web_1      | ERROR in /usr/app/web/src/modules/Utils/Utils.tsx(19,1):
>
> web_1      | max-classes-per-file: A maximum of 1 class per file is allowed.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The comment you're looking for is:

```
/* tslint:disable:max-classes-per-file */
```

Note the lack of `:` at the end.